# Multi-step form in Codeigniter - Redirect

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, curl

I'm building a simple multi-screen form using codeigniter but I'm having some trouble working out how to keep the data and perform some tasks on each stage.

A bit of background on what it's supposed to do:

- User lands on the home page with a form and fills out one field `vehicle reg number`.
- They are then directed to another page that has pulled in their data relating to their `vehicle reg number` via a curl/xml request. As this web service costs per request, I only want to do this once per ip address, per day. Also, when a user refreshes the page it should not perform that call again, rather the data just be there already.
- After the user is on this page, they confirm their details are correct, press next and enter their contact details.
- Then they press submit and receive a confirmation message and one record is inserted into the database.

My idea for this was to record the users ip address. check the database to see if a request today had been submitted with that ip. If not, let it contiue, if so just give them a manual form to complete.

My question is how do I approach this so that when a user goes onto the next stage they have the previous data. Do I make each section a separate form that passes the previous data using hidden fields? This seems a logical way to me as I only need the data if it is a complete request. If they drop off, their data is useless to me anyway.

If i use this approach, how can I prevent the refreshing form and it trying to call via curl again?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: does it contain confidential data? if not, then a javascript multi step form will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, it's confidential and needs to all be kept server-side. My main concern with this is making sure that the webservice is only called once per ip, per day.

Comment: 1. On submit of 1st step of the form, make a unique id of the request against which every entry will be saved in the session. 2. check if the user has called the ip. If yes, then retrieve the info from the database, else exec curl and store it in the DB along with the ip. 3. Later whenever you want, you can get all the data in the session. 4. use database as the storage for session and make it persisting.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a good way to go. Are you able to write this as an answer with how I go about creating a unique id and referring to that? It would be really helpful if you could. I've never done anything like this before. Thanks

Comment: been long since i used codeigniter. Do you use laravel? or else i would have to go back to CI docs again lol.

Comment: I've just started using laravel but this project was already built on CI and just needed this form creating. I hate CI. This multi form thing is such a pain!

Comment: lol ok. this will be a pain in the *blip* cz it is CI but i will see what i can come up with.

Comment: One thing, Ideally id like to not submit into the database until the final stage as they go into a custom CMS that handles the requests once submitted and it would mean changing that to only show complete ones.

Comment: yup. that's why they will be saved in the `session` table, not in the main table. and after a period, they will get deleted if not submitted.